# programmatically get server load information from Apache ServiceMix using JMX

Tags: cxf, monitoring, jmx, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

Is it possible to get the server load information of a webserver deployed on a ServiceMix / Fuse ESB.

I dont want to use Jconsole but get the information by running a java file and writing the values into text file.

Could someone point me to some code that I can run on my machine?

Cheers,
Kunal

Comment: I am a very amateur java developer, I did see some resources but nothing was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also intall jolokia i ServiceMix which exposes a REST interface over JMX. This makes it much easier for non Java developers and programming languages to access the metrics. It's just a HTTP call to get the data.

http://www.jolokia.org/

We use this library for the http://hawt.io management console so we can get the data easily from a moderne HTML5 web console.

Comment: Thanks for the info Claus. I will surely go through this link. Its just that as per the requirement of my project I do need to create a basic java class and get the metrics from there.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code you ask for, but..

Everything in JConsole is accessed through JMX. And everything in JMX is accessible via code as well ([basic tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html)).

So just locate the value/values you are intressted in using JConsole, then just extract them using the JMX api in code.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to figure it out :)